# Why TCP/IP speed depends on the size of sending data?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, winsock, ethernet

When I sent small data (16 bytes and 128 bytes) continuously (use a 100-time loop without any inserted delay), the throughput of TCP_NODELAY setting seems not as good as normal setting. Additionally, TCP-slow-start appeared to affect the transmission in the beginning.

[image]

[image]

The reason is that I want to control a device from PC via Ethernet. The processing time of this device is around several microseconds, but the huge latency of sending command affected the entire system. Could you share me some ways to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

---

Last time, I measured the transfer performance between a Windows-PC and a Linux embedded board. To verify the TCP_NODELAY, I setup a system with two Linux PCs connecting directly with each other, i.e. Linux PC <--> Router <--> Linux PC. The router was only used for two PCs.

The performance without TCP_NODELAY is shown as follows. It is easy to see that the throughput increased significantly when data size >= 64 KB. Additionally, when data size = 16 B, sometimes the received time dropped until 4.2 us. Do you have any idea of this observation?

[image]

The performance with TCP_NODELAY seems unchanged, as shown below.

[image]

The full code can be found in https://www.dropbox.com/s/bupcd9yws5m5hfs/tcpip_code.zip?dl=0

Please share with me your thinking. Thanks in advance.

---

I am doing socket programming to transfer a binary file between a Windows 10 PC and a Linux embedded board. The socket library are winsock2.h and sys/socket.h for Windows and Linux, respectively. The binary file is copied to an array in Windows before sending, and the received data are stored in an array in Linux.

Windows: socket_send(sockfd, &SOPF->array[0], n);

Linux: socket_recv(&SOPF->array[0], connfd);

I could receive all data properly. However, it seems to me that the transfer time depends on the size of sending data. When data size is small, the received throughput is quite low, as shown below.

[image]

Could you please shown me some documents explaining this problem? Thank you in advance.

---

Comment: Are you taking into account packets overhead? When transferring between two contiguous devices (i.e. low chances of NW issues), the bigger the buffer the better. When transfer is between remote devices, errors and re-transmissions come into the scene and hence you need to reduce buffer size to an optimal value.

Comment: Simplistically stated, there are some fixed overheads to send a single packet. So with smaller data sizes you are paying that fixed overhead many more times than with the larger data size.

Comment: TCP/IP also has a feature called "slow start", that throttles the speed as the connection is "warming up". This increases connection stability at the first stages of the connection and decreases overall network traffic in relation to "lost" packets.

Comment: Are you sure you're receiving all the data? Code please.

Comment: Trace the communication between hosts, and analyze the receiver TCP window.

Comment: I am really interested to hear of "no delay" fixes the issue. It would be awesome if you could post another table with "no delay" turned on...

Comment: @EJP You can find my code in dropbox link. Thanks.

Comment: @bremen_matt I posted the result with TCP_NODELAY. Please share your idea. Thanks.

Comment: Oh I didn't see the link to the code in the first post. I thought you were averaging the results over many runs, but it doesn't seem that you are. Since you aren't averaging the results, I think that Myst is likely correct. I would try averaging the results over a few runs (by sending the same file in a loop,  for example), and I would guess that you will see the same throughput regardless of size. My previous answer about disabling Nagles algorithm is almost definitely incorrect in this case...

Comment: @bremen_matt I tried to run the code continuously. However, the throughput changed according to data size. Please let me know your idea. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you are going to be able to do much about anything for packages as small as 16 bytes because of the inherent overhead. But I would guess that for packages of size >= 512, you should be able to see flat results with NO DELAY = false once you start taking into account warm start like on your newest plots.

Answer (score 4):

To establish a tcp connection, you need a 3-way handshake: SYN, SYN-ACK, ACK.  Then the sender will start to send some data.  How much depends on the initial congestion window (configurable on linux, don't know on windows).  As long as the sender receives timely ACKs, it will continue to send, as long as the receivers advertised window has the space (use socket option SO_RCVBUF to set).  Finally, to close the connection also requires a FIN, FIN-ACK, ACK.

So my best guess without more information is that the overhead of setting up and tearing down the TCP connection has a huge affect on the overhead of sending a small number of bytes.  Nagle's algorithm (disabled with TCP_NODELAY) shouldn't have much affect as long as the writer is effectively writing quickly.  It only prevents sending less than full MSS segements, which should increase transfer efficiency in this case, where the sender is simply sending data as fast as possible.  The only effect I can see is that the final less than full MSS segment might need to wait for an ACK, which again would have more impact on the short transfers as compared to the longer transfers.

To illustrate this, I sent one byte using netcat (`nc`) on my loopback interface (which isn't a physical interface, and hence the bandwidth is "infinite"):

```
$ nc -l 127.0.0.1 8888 >/dev/null &
[1] 13286
$ head -c 1 /dev/zero | nc 127.0.0.1 8888 >/dev/null
```

And here is a network capture in wireshark:

[image]

It took a total of 237 microseconds to send one byte, which is a measly 4.2KB/second.  I think you can guess that if I sent 2 bytes, it would take essentially the same amount of time for an effective rate of 8.2KB/second, a 100% improvement!

The best way to diagnose performance problems in networks is to get a network capture and analyze it.

Comment: It seems that you are speaking about "TCP window", but calling it "congestion window" - it is not clear to me. Beside, it is worth your last sentence: the best way to diagnose is to analyze the traffic.

Comment: @linuxfan there is the recieve window,  which is advertised by the receiver.  A sender will not send more data that is advertised by the receiver.  The receiver can increase this to allow more data to be sent if it is "slow" in processing the data.  The congestion window is maintained by the sender, and relates to how much data a sender will send without an ACK.  The initial congestion window is how much data a sender will send without an ACK during slow start, and is configurable systemwide on linux.  You could increase the size to allow startup to sent more data.

Comment: No, it is not exactly so - especially, the receiver window should not be increased if the receiver "is slow in processing"; a big receiver window is good to defeat latencies which are always present.

Comment: @linuxfan I agree that the receive window is most usefully increased above the bandwidth delay product to insure a smooth transfer in the face of high latency and/or bandwidth.  It nevertheless can be a means of dealing with a slow consumer, e.g. when your java consumer decides to GC for 10 seconds.

Comment: @JimD Thank you for your comment. Is there any way to transfer a few bytes of data at very low latency, i.e. smaller than 1us, by Linux command or library? The reason is that I sent a command from PC to a device via Ethernet. The processing time of this device is around several microsecond, but the huge latency of sending command affected the entire system. Thank you.

Comment: @ThuanN. Either establish a TCP connection and send the commands through the established TCP connection when you need to, or use UDP.  UDP is not a reliable protocol though, so you will have to design some sort of protocol to make sure that the command was received or won't be executed twice.

Comment: @ThuanN.  Note that if you establish a TCP connection and use it to send frequent, small commands you will definitely need to set TCP_NODELAY to make sure your small command will not be delayed.  If the commands are very frequent, you might run into problems with the congestion window not wanting to send your commands.  You could get around this with a pool of open connections that you rotate through.  In general UDP is preferred for low latency applications. TCP has so many reasons *not* to send!  However it can be difficult to traverse a firewall with UDP.

Answer (score 2):

When you make your test with a significative amount of data, for example your bigger test (512Mib, 536 millions bytes), the following happens.

The data is sent by TCP layer, breaking them in *segments* of a certain length. Let assume segments of 1460 bytes, so there will be about 367,000 segments.

For every segment transmitted there is a overhead (control and management added data to ensure good transmission): in your setup, there are 20 bytes for TCP, 20 for IP, and 16 for ethernet, for a total of 56 bytes **every segment**. Please note that this number is the *minimum*, not accounting the ethernet preamble for example; moreover sometimes IP and TCP overhead can be bigger because optional fields.

Well, 56 bytes for every segment (367,000 segments!) means that when you transmit 512Mib, you also transmit 56*367,000 = 20M bytes on the line. The total number of bytes becomes 536+20 = 556 millions of bytes, or 4.448 millions of bits. If you divide this number of bits by the time elapsed, 4.6 seconds, you get a bitrate of 966 megabits per second, which is higher than what you calculated not taking in account the overhead.

From the above calculus, it seems that your ethernet is a *gigabit*. It's maximum transfer rate should be 1,000 megabits per second and you are getting really near to it. The rest of the time is due to more overhead we didn't account for, and some latencies that are always present and tend to be cancelled as more data is transferred (but they will never be defeated completely).

I would say that your setup is ok. But this is *for big data transfers*. As the size of the transfer decreases, the overhead in the data, latencies of the protocol and other nice things get more and more important. For example, if you transmit 16 bytes in 165 microseconds (first of your tests), the result is 0.78 Mbps; if it took 4.2 us, about 40 times less, the bitrate would be about 31 Mbps (40 times bigger). These numbers are lower than expected.

In reality, you don't transmit 16 bytes, you transmit at least 16+56 = 72 bytes, which is 4.5 times more, so the real transfer rate of the link is also bigger. But, you see, transmitting 16 bytes on a TCP/IP link is the same as measuring the flow rate of an empty acqueduct by dropping some tears of water in it: the tears get lost before they reach the other end. This is because TCP/IP and ethernet are designed to carry much more data, with reliability.

Comments and answers in this page point out many of those mechanisms that trade bitrate and reactivity for reliability: the 3-way TCP handshake, the Nagle algorithm, checksums and other overhead, and so on.

Given the design of TCP+IP and ethernet, it is very normal that, for little data, performances are not optimal. From your tests you see that the transfer rate climbs steeply when the data size reaches 64Kbytes. This is not a coincidence.

From a comment you leaved above, it seems that you are looking for a low-latency communication, instead than one with big bandwidth. It is a common mistake to confuse different kind of performances. Moreover, in respect to this, I must say that TCP/IP and ethernet are completely **non-deterministic**. They are quick, of course, but nobody can say how much because there are too many layers in between. Even in your simple setup, if a single packet get lost or corrupted, you can expect delays of **seconds**, not microseconds.

If you really want something with low latency, you should use something else, for example a CAN. Its design is exactly what you want: it transmits little data with high speed, low latency, deterministic time (just microseconds after you transmitted a packet, *you know* if it has been received or not. To be more precise: exactly at the end of the transmission of a packet **you know** if it reached the destination or not).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helps a lot.

Comment: btw, 0.096 is in MBytes/s and 0.78 is in Mbits/s.

Comment: @ThuanN. You are right, thanks for pointing it out - I corrected my post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

TCP sockets typically have a buffer size internally. In many implementations, it will wait a little bit of time before sending a packet to see if it can fill up the remaining space in the buffer before sending. This is called [Nagle's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle's_algorithm). I assume that the times you report above are not due to overhead in the TCP packet, but due to the fact that the TCP waits for you to queue up more data before actually sending.

Most socket implementations therefore have a parameter or function called something like TcpNoDelay which can be false (default) or true. I would try messing with that and seeing if that affects your throughput. Essentially these flags will enable/disable Nagle's algorithm.

Comment: This is more commonly known as the [Nagle Algorithm for send coalescing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle's_algorithm)

Comment: Yes. I should have put that in the post. Updating now.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll check the TCP_NODELAY soon.